# Nullpointerexception у ImageView в NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, исключения, android-navigation-drawer, android-button

Всем доброго времени суток! Появилась проблема: есть `NavigationDrawer`, который присоединен к MainActivity. Вот код:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_toolbar"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

В `nav_header` есть кнопка выхода. Как правильно найти кнопку в MainActivity.onCreate в моем коде, чтобы добавить к ней слушателя? Код ниже не работает (NullPointerException):

**MainActivity.java**

```
ImageButton exitButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mNavigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

**NullPointerException**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка находится в хэдере. Значит надо получить хэдер и уже в нем искать кпопку. Как-то так:

```
navigationView.getHeader(0).findViewById(ID)
```

Comment: Благодарю. Забыл добавить getHeader(0), поэтому и была ошибка.